# looping through arrays at different rates

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script

`filesNamed` is the reference array with which I want to accumulate and set data. So that for each index in `filesNamed`, arrays from `emailData` containing the same movie title should be accumulated and eventually set in a range within google spreadsheet. Setting data in a range aside, I am having issues with the very first part of this task.

```
var filesNamed = [
                  ["Happiness","Karate for Life","Dogtooth","The Streetfighter","Mind Game","The Raid","The Hole","Plaga Zombie","Funny Games"]
                ];

var emailData = [
                      ["Date","Happiness","Sender 1","Receiver 1","Subject 1" ],
                      ["Date","Happiness","Sender 1","Receiver 1","Subject 1" ],
                      ["Date","Happiness","Sender 1","Receiver 1","Subject 1" ],
                      ["Date","Happiness","Sender 1","Receiver 1","Subject 1" ],
                      ["Date","Happiness","Sender 1","Receiver 1","Subject 1" ],
                      ["Date","Karate for Life","Sender 2","Receiver 2","Subject 2" ],
                      ["Date","Karate for Life","Sender 2","Receiver 2","Subject 2" ],
                      ["Date","Karate for Life","Sender 2","Receiver 2","Subject 2" ],
                      ["Date","Karate for Life","Sender 2","Receiver 2","Subject 2" ],
                      ["Date","Karate for Life","Sender 2","Receiver 2","Subject 2" ],
                      ["Date","Karate for Life","Sender 2","Receiver 2","Subject 2" ],
                      ["Date","Dogtooth","Sender 3","Receiver 3","Subject 3" ],
                      ["Date","Dogtooth","Sender 3","Receiver 3","Subject 3" ],
                      ["Date","Dogtooth","Sender 3","Receiver 3","Subject 3" ],
                      ["Date","Dogtooth","Sender 3","Receiver 3","Subject 3" ],
                      ["Date","The Streetfighter","Sender 4","Receiver 4","Subject 4" ],
                      ["Date","The Streetfighter","Sender 4","Receiver 4","Subject 4" ],
                      ["Date","The Streetfighter","Sender 4","Receiver 4","Subject 4" ],
                      ["Date","The Streetfighter","Sender 4","Receiver 4","Subject 4" ],
                      ["Date","Mind Game","Sender 5","Receiver 5","Subject 5" ],
                      ["Date","Mind Game","Sender 5","Receiver 5","Subject 5" ],
                      ["Date","Mind Game","Sender 5","Receiver 5","Subject 5" ],
                      ["Date","Mind Game","Sender 5","Receiver 5","Subject 5" ],
                      ["Date","The Raid","Sender 15","Receiver 15","Subject 15" ],
                      ["Date","The Raid","Sender 15","Receiver 15","Subject 15" ],
                      ["Date","The Raid","Sender 15","Receiver 15","Subject 15" ],
                      ["Date","The Raid","Sender 15","Receiver 15","Subject 15" ],
                      ["Date","The Hole","Sender 25","Receiver 25","Subject 25" ],
                      ["Date","The Hole","Sender 25","Receiver 25","Subject 25" ],
                      ["Date","The Hole","Sender 25","Receiver 25","Subject 25" ],
                      ["Date","Plaga Zombie","Sender 35","Receiver 35","Subject 35" ],
                      ["Date","Plaga Zombie","Sender 35","Receiver 35","Subject 35" ],
                      ["Date","Plaga Zombie","Sender 35","Receiver 35","Subject 35" ],
                      ["Date","Funny Games","Sender 45","Receiver 45","Subject 45" ],
                      ["Date","Funny Games","Sender 45","Receiver 45","Subject 45" ]
                   ];
```

the problem with the code below is that, while the first time looping through `filesNamed[0][0] == emailData[0][1]` returns a match, the second time through, both for loops are incremented- yet we haven't finished accumulating from `emailData` all arrays with title `Happiness` above (there's still 4 more). I think the counter should only increment after the loop breaks, signifying that we have reached the last of arrays belonging to the move Happiness. I tried putting the counter(l++) in the else statement but this does not work.

**as simply as i can state it:** i want all the data in an array belonging to a specific movie title to go in its own spreadsheet. each sub-array (starting with date) should go on its own row, of which the indices will span 5 columns.

```
function theo (){

  Logger.log("emailData.length: " + emailData.length);
  Logger.log("filesNamed[0].length: " + filesNamed[0].length);
  for(var i=0;i<emailData.length;i++){
    for(var l=0;l<filesNamed[0].length;l++){
      if(filesNamed[0][l] == emailData[i][1]){
        Logger.log("");
        Logger.log("match");
        Logger.log("emailData[0]): " + emailData[i][1]);
        Logger.log("filesNamed[0][l]: " + filesNamed[0][l]);
        Logger.log("");
        Logger.log("l: "+l);
        Logger.log("i: "+i);
      } else {
        Logger.log("");
        Logger.log("broke");
        Logger.log("emailData[0]): " + emailData[i][1]);
        Logger.log("filesNamed[0][l]: " + filesNamed[0][l]);
        Logger.log("");
        Logger.log("l: "+l);
        Logger.log("i: "+i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*The Happiness spreadsheet will contain 5 rows. The Karate for Life spreadsheet will contain 6 rows. The Dogtooth spreadsheet will contain 4 rows. and so on...*

A friend suggested I learn about iterators and I will, but I was wondering if there was another way to structure my double loop to get something closer to the original method working as well. There are a few more lessons to get out of this fail.

Comment: other than logging as a debug method, what is your hoped for out put from those loops? you say accumulated email arrays, but its not clear what you want or why what you have isn't working.

Comment: i explain in between the two code snippets why this isn't working. The idea is to set all the arrays belonging to a particular Movie Title into rows of a particular google spreadsheet with the same Movie Title. This list will continue to accumulate new movie titles, and each movie title will continue to accumulate arrays.

Comment: i'm afraid i'm not getting the problem. running `theo` loops through `filesNamed` each time it increments `emailData`, but what is the link to filesNamed specifically? You want all the arrays in emailData to be individual rows or concatenated per title?

Comment: from your question edits i think you are already getting what you wanted but not what you expected. swap the loops around and you'll see the same matches but in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know if there is a match of the movie title.  You can determine if an array has a certain element by using `indexOf()`.

```
var isItA_Match = filesNamed.indexOf("Happiness");
```

If the word "Happiness" is found anywhere in the "filesNamed" array, then an index number is assigned to the variable "isItA_Match".  If there is no match, then a value of -1 is returned.

This code is not complete or correct, but hopefully you get the idea of the logic I'm trying to use:

```
function theo() {

  Logger.log("emailData.length: " + emailData.length);
  Logger.log("filesNamed[0].length: " + filesNamed[0].length);

  var happinessArray = [];
  var karateArray = [];

  //Create all the arrays for each movie Title
  for(var i=0;i<emailData.length;i++) {

    var elmtToMatch = emailData[i][1];
    var isItA_Match = filesNamed.indexOf(elmtToMatch);

    if (isItA_Match > -1) {
      Logger.log("match");
      //put data into correct Array
      if (matchCorrectArray) {
         happinessArray = data;
      }
    };
  };
};
```

Using `indexOf()` checks every element in the array.  You don't need to iterate through every element to look for a match.  So that avoids needing a loop.

Once you get all the arrays with the correct data, you could invoke another function to then write the data to each respective spreadsheet.  Create an object that matches movies names to spreadsheet ID's.

### Create object that matches movie name to spreadsheet ID

```
var objMovieToSheetID = {"Happiness":"48rjdjfoierawj", "Karate for Life":"894ilkdjfhwo"};
```

### Create an object that matches movie name to array name

```
var objMovieToArrayName = {"Happiness":"Hap", "Karate for Life":"Kar"};
```

Call a function to loop through the process of opening each spreadsheet

```
function addDataToSheets() {

  //An object that matches the movie title to the spreadsheet ID
  var objMovieToSheetID = {"Happiness":"48rjdjfoierawj", "Karate for Life":"894ilkdjfhwo"};

  var objMovieToArrayName = {"Happiness":"Hap", "Karate for Life":"Kar"};

  //Loop through all the movie titles and add data to each spreadsheet
  for(var i=0; i<objSheetToArrayName.length; i++){

    // The code below opens a spreadsheet using its ID and logs the name for it.
    // Note that the spreadsheet is NOT physically opened on the client side.
    // It is opened on the server only (for modification by the script).

    //get each movie name from the array in sequence by index
    var movieName = filesNamed[i];
    //Retrieve the spreadsheet ID from the object that matches movie name to spreadsheet ID
    var ssID = objSheetToArrayName[movieName];
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
    Logger.log(ss.getName());

    var dataToAppend = emailData[objMovieToArrayName[movieName]];
    // Appends a new row with to the bottom of the
    // spreadsheet containing the values in the array
    sheet.appendRow(dataToAppend);
  };

};
```

Comment: that's what i figured too, but its the specifics of the accumulation i'm not clear what mrcni wants. separate files per film title, separate sheets etc.?

Comment: Well, worst case scenario is I chance getting a down vote.  ;)  Sometimes I answer hoping for the best.

Comment: i want all the data belonging to a specific movie title to go in their own spreadsheets. each sub-array should go on its own row, of which the indices will span 5 columns.

Comment: I'd create an object that matches each movie name to the spreadsheet ID of the Sheet where you want the data to be stored.  I updated my answer.  I haven't worked out the code for all the arrays, but hopefully you can see where I was going with it.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest accumulation that I think you are looking for could be made something like this.

```
function theo2() {
  var accumulatedFiles = filesNamed[0].map(
    function (title) {
      var emails = this;
      return {
        title: title,
        emails: emails.filter(
          function (email) {
            var title = this;
            return email[1] == title;
          },
          title
        )
      };
    },
    emailData
  );
}
```

this produces an array of objects where the first index is as per the film title index in `filesNamed`, the title attribute the title and the emails attribute an array of arrays within that index are those matching the title.

A by product is that it only returns emails that have titles matching the original source list. If you want instead to allow the email responses to determine the title accumulation and not have a `filesNamed` array at all you can be even more compact.

[image: Snapshot of the debugger of the returned object]

This will be a start you can use to then either populate sheets or whatever you want to do.

As Sandy points out the function above forgoes the use of loops but instead `.map()` and `.filter()`. Loops work too, but I personally prefer the semantic description and yet terseness of the methods.

For completeness a loop form might be thus (***guess what, it's what you already had more or less***):

```
function theo3() {
  var accumulatedFiles = [],
      filmEmails = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < filesNamed[0].length; i += 1) {    
    filmEmails = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < emailData.length; j += 1) {
      if (emailData[j][1] == filesNamed[0][i]) {
        filmEmails.push(emailData[j]);
      }
    }
    accumulatedFiles.push({title: filesNamed[0][i], emails: filmEmails});
  }
}
```

Comment: Some links to methods:  [map Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679976(v=vs.94).aspx) and: [filter Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679973(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: They are not supported by all browsers, but are fully supported by Google Apps Script – albeit the IDE debugger breaks if you add breakpoints within them.